# Multiple of three checker (python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to write some code to check if a number is divisible by three with the idea that if you add up all of the digits, it should be divisible by three if it is a multiple of three and if not it shouldn't be divisible by three. However it keeps telling me that the line `ans += (num[a])` is `"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'"`.

Heres my code:

```
num = input("Enter the number you want to check: ")
chara = int(len(num))
a = int(0)
ans = int(0)
while a <= chara:
    ans += (num[a])
    a += 1

if ans % 3 == 0:
    print(num, " is a multiple of three.")
else:
    print(num, " is not a multiple of three")
```

I would really appreciate an answer,
Thanks

Comment: @timgeb, they are actually  using the mod operator

Comment: you cannot add an int and a string, `num[a]` pulls the first character from your input string

Answer (score 1):

the return value from the input() function is a string.  You will need to convert it to an integer before you can add it to another integer.

```
while a < chara:
    ans += int((num[a]))
```

Note:  This comes with several assumptions.
1.) The num[a] actually is a number.
2.) The value is not a floating point number.

Anytime you accept input from a user you should validate it before using it.

Comment: This will fail with an IndexError

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add an int and a string, `num[a]` pulls the first character from your input string initially so you cannot add it to an int i.e `a`, your code is doing a lot more than it needs to, you just need to cast each digit to int and `sum` then check if that sum % 3 is 0:

```
num = input("Enter the number you want to check: ")

ans = sum(map(int, num))

if ans % 3 == 0:
    print(num, " is a multiple of three.")
else:
    print(num, " is not a multiple of three")
```

If you want to create a variable set to 0 initially, you don't need to call `int(0)` just set it to 0 i.e  `a = 0`, if you wanted a loop, forget the while and just iterate over the string, you don't need to index a string in python to get each character.

```
num = input("Enter the number you want to check: ")
a = 0
ans = 0
for d in num:
    ans += int(d)

if ans % 3 == 0:
    print(num, " is a multiple of three.")
else:
    print(num, " is not a multiple of three")
```

Even if you cast to int in your own code you would eventually get an indexError with  `while a <= chara:`, indexing starts at `0` so `num[len(num)]` is going to be one past the end of the string.